# Delete ALL Python 2.7 modules and Python from Mac

Tags: python, homebrew, uninstallation, removeall

I had Python 2.7 for few months on my Mac and after installing one module - every other module got corrupted. Tried several hours of different ways to repair but did not work. Virtual-env also does now work now.
I would like to remove ALL Python modules from my Mac along with Python and reinstall it with Brew (or other recommended tool).

Packages are here: `/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

How do I do that?
Should I remove this whole folder above or what is the proper way?
(after reinstalling Python with just brew - it did not remove this folder and therefore same problem show up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it there are 2 changes:

- remove the /Users/user/anaconda2 directory
- change your path to not use any /Users/user/anaconda2 directories.

However I suggest you download Anaconda again and use environments rather than your root folder for everything.  Use conda to install packages when possible (most of the time really) and use conda-environments on a per project basis to install packages (Instead of cluttering up your main environment).

This way if you have this problem again you can delete the conda environment and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks! That helped to go back to beginning. What is the recommended way to properly install Anaconda for Python 2?

Comment: There is a graphical installer to download on the right https://www.continuum.io/downloads#osx  Double click it after downloading.